# RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported Pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I recently shifted to pytorch from keras and I am still trying to understand how all this work. Below is the code I have implemented to classify mnist dataset using a simple MLP. Just like I used to do in keras I have flattend each of 28x28 image into a vector of 784 , and I have also created a one-hot representation for my labels.
In the model I was hoping that given a vector of 784 the model would output a one-hot vector with probabilities,but as soon as my code reaches to compute the loss I get the following error :

```
RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

Below is my code :

```
    import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import time
from torch import nn, optim
from keras.datasets import mnist
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

RANDOM_SEED = 42
np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)


# ----------------------------------------------------

class MnistDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, data_size=0):

        (x, y), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()

        x = [i.flatten() for i in x]
        x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float32)

        if data_size < 0 or data_size > len(y):
            assert ("Data size should be between 0 to number of files in the dataset")

        if data_size == 0:
            data_size = len(y)

        self.data_size = data_size

        # picking 'data_size' random samples
        self.x = x[:data_size]
        self.y = y[:data_size]

        # scaling between 0-1
        self.x = (self.x / 255)

        # Creating one-hot representation of target
        y_encoded = []
        for label in y:
            encoded = np.zeros(10)
            encoded[label] = 1
            y_encoded.append(encoded)

        self.y = np.array(y_encoded)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data_size

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        x_sample = self.x[index]
        label = self.y[index]

        return x_sample, label


# ----------------------------------------------------

num_train_samples = 10000
num_test_samples = 2000

# Each generator returns a single
# sample & its label on each iteration.
mnist_train = MnistDataset(data_size=num_train_samples)
mnist_test = MnistDataset(data_size=num_test_samples)

# Each generator returns a batch of samples on each iteration.
train_loader = DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)  # 79 batches
test_loader = DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)  # 16 batches


# ----------------------------------------------------

# Defining the Model Architecture

class MLP(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 100)
        self.act1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 50)
        self.act2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(50, 10)
        self.act3 = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.act1(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.act2(self.fc2(x))
        output = self.act3(self.fc3(x))

        return output


# ----------------------------------------------------

model = MLP()

# Defining optimizer and loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9)

# ----------------------------------------------------

# Training the model

epochs = 10

print("Training Started...")

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch_index, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):

        optimizer.zero_grad()  # Zero the gradients
        outputs = model(inputs)  # Forward pass
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)  # Compute the Loss
        loss.backward()  # Compute the Gradients
        optimizer.step()  # Update the parameters

        # Evaluating the model
        total = 0
        correct = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(test_loader):
                outputs = model(inputs)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                total += targets.size(0)
                correct += predicted.eq(targets.data).cpu().sum()
            print('Epoch : {} Test Acc : {}'.format(epoch, (100. * correct / total)))

print("Training Completed Sucessfully")

# ----------------------------------------------------
```

I also read some other posts related to the same problem & most of them said that the CrossEntropy loss the target has to be a single number ,which totally gets over my head.Can someone please explain a solution.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`, you don't need one-hot representation of the label, you just need to pass the prediction's logit, which shape is `(batch_size, n_class)`, and a target vector `(batch_size,)`

So just pass in the label index vector `y` instead of one-hot vector.

Fixed of your code:

```py
class MnistDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, data_size=0):

        (x, y), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()

        x = [i.flatten() for i in x]
        x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float32)

        if data_size < 0 or data_size > len(y):
            assert ("Data size should be between 0 to number of files in the dataset")

        if data_size == 0:
            data_size = len(y)

        self.data_size = data_size

        # picking 'data_size' random samples
        self.x = x[:data_size]
        self.y = y[:data_size]

        # scaling between 0-1
        self.x = (self.x / 255)

        self.y = y # <--

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data_size

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        x_sample = self.x[index]
        label = self.y[index]

        return x_sample, label
```

Take a look at Pytorch example for more detail:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

Comment: Yeah I got it , but then how do does it calculate the loss ? After training the model, when i tried to print the outputs from the model and the target vector , i got this :

Comment: tensor([3, 1, 5])                             
                                                                                                                                  
       tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.5532,
          0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000, 10.9873,  5.8783,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,
          1.3808,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.2514,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,
          0.0000,  0.0000]], grad_fn=<ReluBackward0>)

Comment: Here the first tensor is my target labels and the second tensor is the output from the model. For example the target is a single digit whereas the model outputs a vector of 10 , so how does the loss gets computed ?

Comment: The output tensor seems incorrect, should it only has two dimension? Here you got 3-d tensor with shape (3, 1, 5) and none has size of 10. Could you reconfirm?

Comment: About how it compute the loss, it would take item  `c` in `output` where `c` is a label from 0 to 9, then compute as `-output[c] + log(sum(exp(output)))`. This is from the first equation in the documentation. This is done for each item in the batch

Comment: (3,1,5) are the target labels for the model , the later is the output that model gave as a prediction.

Comment: I think I should rephrase my question,I am asking that how is it that the model outputs a vector of probabilities for each sample , even though we have only given the model a single digit as a target & not the one-hot representation.

Comment: Actual label :  2
Model Output : tensor([1.6220e-05, 2.9183e-08, 9.9999e-01, 1.8512e-05, 2.5371e-09, 1.8858e-04,  6.1971e-09, 7.0195e-06, 1.0060e-03, 4.0664e-04], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)

Comment: I see. My mis-looked the tensor. Regarding to your question, this single digit is a compact form of the target one-hot representation, where value `c` means the target one-hot distribution has 1 at position c. It takes less space and easier to implement so people prefer it. We do not directly give that number to the model, we give it to `CrossEntropyLoss` and it decodes the target for the model

Comment: Ah ! So in the end the model internally creates a one-hot representation for each label , is that it ?